# Why is quering via a django QuerySet much slower than just using a cursor in Django?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset

**THE SIMPLE VERSION:**

Why is raw SQL in Django more efficient than the QuerySet interface?

**SOME DETAILS:**

I have a query that returns ~ 700,000 (could be more) rows from a PostgreSQL database. Each row contains a few double values, some strings, and some integers. So a moderately complex return.

It is simple in form (oversimplified example):

```
SELECT (a,b,c) FROM table WHERE d=something AND e=somethings ORDER BY a;
```

When I use the model interface and .filter() to make the query the execution of the query takes ~30 seconds. This is unacceptable.

I have tried using all of the suggested methods. (Iterator,memory efficient iterator,etc...)

However, when I do the EXACT same query using `connection.cursor` ... and `fetchall` in Django the query drops to about 5 seconds to execute.

What overhead does using the django model interface produce that accounts for this significant performance difference?

**UPDATE:**

*Django QuerySet code:*

```
c_layer_points = models.layer_points.objects.filter(location_id__location_name=region,season_id__season_name=season,line_path_id=c_line_path.pk,radar_id=c_radar.pk,gps_time__gte=start_gps,gps_time__lte=stop_gps).order_by('gps_time').values_list('gps_time','twtt','pick_type','quality','layer_id')
```

EXACT same query in fast version:

```
# OPEN a cursor
cursor = connection.cursor()

# EXECUTE the query
cursor.execute(query)
transaction.commit_unless_managed()

# FETCH all the rows
rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

Where 'query' is the EXACT string representation of the connection.queries code generated from the Queryset.

**UPDATE 2:**

The timing is done using `line_profiler` and taking the sum of time from initial query to returned list of tuples (Exact same return by both options). I've also tested the time the raw query takes directly on the database (exact same for both). The discrepancy in timing is when it's done from python via each method.

Comment: Can you give us the django ORM code that you used? Because without knowing what exactly you did, it is indeed impossible for us to judge if its django at fault or you.
@danihp: Yes, that would explain the poor results.

Comment: How are you measuring the query duration?  Could the extra time be marshalling the data into the python objects/django models?

Comment: I would vote to close this question, but 'Not a real question' is not at this time an option to close it.

Comment: Added an update to measuring query time. @danihp How is this not a real question? I'm asking why one method is so much slower than another while performing the same task.

Comment: This is exactly what I did. I took the generated query from c_layer_points, and tested the EXACT string in both methods. I tested it directly via the psql interface and then via django using both described methods. The discrepancy is in the time of each method - the known database time.

Answer (score 3):

If you timed the two code segments in the update to your question, then yes, the difference is because django is marshalling the results of the DB query into 700,000 python objects (i.e., it's calling `object.__init__()` 700,000 times).

There is nothing wrong with using raw sql for the query.  This is a case where it might be advised, depending on what you do with the info.

That said .... do you need 700,000 objects in the response?  Will 700,000 items in a dict do instead (that's what the raw sql query returns)?  Or can you limit the rows you get back with pagination or query-set slicing?

Comment: Were tied to all the objects in the response. A remote MATLAB client is contacting the database for the data and then using the actual data for something. Using raw sql we have gotten the time down to something reasonable.

Comment: If the data is collected for a remote client, then you definitely don't need the python objects.  The plain dict is perfectly sufficient for your needs.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "plain dict". If your referring to the return from the raw query, then yes your correct and that's the path we've chosen. There is no need for the Django Object. If not, what are you referring too?

Comment: I meant a dict with strings for keys and values.  Actually I misled you before:  Model.objects.raw () returns a queryset of objects.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries  The thing that returns the DB contents as strings is https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly.  Sorry for the confusion.  And the late reply.